# Como exibir imagens com tamanho proporcional à tela com libgdx?

Tags: android, jogos, libgdx

Como faço para exibir as imagens do meu jogo com o tamanho proporcional ao tamanho da tela do dispositivo, de maneira que se uma imagem tem a largura de 1/3 da tela numa tela 480x800 também deverá ter os mesmos 1/3 na 320x480 ou 720x1280? Penso que seja com '`camera.setToOrtho()`', alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Você está usando uma Sprite para a imagem ?

Comment: sim amigo. Actor com Sprite

Comment: seria mais ou menos isso (https://igoralves1.github.io/) o que vc quer? A imgem pode ser aberta por quaqluer dispositivo. Mas no meu caso eu escolhi usar 100% da tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, trabalhei muito pouco com libgdx, mas pelo que vi, você pode usar [Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) para redimensionar sua imagem.Porém, confesso que nunca testei desta forma.

Uma outra solução, que já vi sendo implementada é criar sua própria função para redimensionar seu Sprite, como por exemplo:

```
 public static float MINHA_PROPORCAO = WIDTH_IMAGEM / Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); // Calcula uma proporção baseada no tamanho da tela.

  public static Sprite CriarSprite(Texture textura) {

   Sprite sprite = new Sprite(textura);
   sprite.getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear,TextureFilter.Linear);
   sprite.setSize(sprite.getWidth() / MINHA_PROPORCAO ,
   sprite.getHeight() / MINHA_PROPORCAO );
   return sprite;
  }
```

Espero que ajude :)

Comment: OK, SCALE_RATIO é a constante proporção?

Comment: Isso mesmo, vou editar desculpe

Comment: @EmersonBarcellos Se a resposta te ajudou e sanou suas dúvidas, considere conceder a gratificação prometida :)