# Como resgatar uma variável de um Actor no Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Eu tenho o seguinte Actor:

```
public class Carta extends Actor {
Sprite sprite;
public static int val, pos, peso;
Texture texture;

public Carta(int valor, int posicao) {
    val = valor;
    pos = posicao;

    switch (val) {
        case 1:
            texture = new Texture("espada.png");
            peso = 3;
            break;
        case 2:
            texture = new Texture("basto.jpg");
            peso = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            texture = new Texture("tres.jpg");
            peso = 1;
            break;

    }


    sprite = new Sprite(texture);

}


public void draw(Batch batch, float pAlfa) {
    final Color c = getColor();
    batch.setColor(c.r, c.g, c.b, c.a * pAlfa);

    batch.draw(sprite, getX(), getY(), this.getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());
    batch.setColor(c.r, c.g, c.b, 1f);
    //this.setOrigin(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight());

}

public void act(float delta) {

    super.act(delta);
}
```

}

E eu chamo este actor:

```
...
carta1 = new Carta(1,2);
carta1.setBounds(100,200, 100, 250);

carta2 = new Carta(2,3);
carta2.setBounds(100,300, 100, 250);

stage.addActor(carta1);
stage.addActor(carta2);
...
```

Então eu resgato a variável `int peso` com `carta1.peso` ou `carta2.peso`, e me retorna sempre o peso do actor `carta2`, alguém sabe por quê acontece isso?

Comment: Amigo @ramaral será que você pode me ajudar nesta questão?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Olá, Emerson

Não seria porque você colocou a variável peso como static? Static torna sua variável única para qualquer instância da classe Carta, pois o atributo peso de todas as instâncias passam a apontar para o mesmo endereço de memória. Os objetos carta1 e carta2 tem seu atributo peso apontando para o mesmo endereço de memória e, sendo assim, se você colocar o valor 1 nesse endereço através de carta1, carta2.peso também lerá esse valor 1 na memória.

A primeira instanciação `carta1 = new Carta(1,2)` faz com que o peso seja igual a 3, então, toda instância de Carta terá o atributo peso igual a 3. A segunda instanciação `carta2 = new Carta(2,3)`  altera o valor do peso, faz com que o peso seja igual a 2, o que fará com que o atributo de peso de qualquer instância de carta, inclusive carta1, também seja igual a 2.

Faça um teste com esse código abaixo:

```
public class Teste {
    static int variavelEstatica = 1;

    public Teste() {

    }

    public void setVariavelEstatica(int valor) {
       variavelEstatica = valor;
    }

    public int getVariavelEstatica() {
      return variavelEstatica ;
    }

}

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Teste teste1 = new Teste();
         Teste teste2 = new Teste();
         Teste teste3 = new Teste();

         System.out.println("Teste1: " + teste1.getVariavelEstatica());
         System.out.println("Teste2: " + teste2.getVariavelEstatica());
         System.out.println("Teste3: " + teste3.getVariavelEstatica());

         teste1.setVariavelEstatica(55);

         System.out.println("Teste1: " + teste1.getVariavelEstatica());
         System.out.println("Teste2: " + teste2.getVariavelEstatica());
         System.out.println("Teste3: " + teste3.getVariavelEstatica());


         teste2.setVariavelEstatica(66);

         System.out.println("Teste1: " + teste1.getVariavelEstatica());
         System.out.println("Teste2: " + teste2.getVariavelEstatica());
         System.out.println("Teste3: " + teste3.getVariavelEstatica());

         teste3.setVariavelEstatica(77);

         System.out.println("Teste1: " + teste1.getVariavelEstatica());
         System.out.println("Teste2: " + teste2.getVariavelEstatica());
         System.out.println("Teste3: " + teste3.getVariavelEstatica());
    }

}
```

Espero que tenha conseguido explicar.

Comment: Muito obrigado, além de certa a sua resposta foi  muito esclarecedora, parabéns pelo conhecimento adquirido amigo.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado, @EmersonBarcellos! Sei o quanto é difícil ficar sem entender o que pode estar acontecendo. Novos olhos sempre ajudam! Aqui torcendo para receber a recompensa!

Comment: por favor veja isso [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134534/como-exibir-imagens-com-tamanho-proporcional-%C3%A0-tela-com-libgdx)